# multiuser loging not verifying password and session

Tags: php, mysql

Following my code that give me folder wise login but not verifying my password and session.

Without switch case if else condition it work but then only tow role are working
I need a multiple role

```
ob_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
$userName = '';
$passError = '';
$error = false;
if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $userName = trim($_POST['userName']);
    $userName = strip_tags($userName);
    $userName = htmlspecialchars($userName);
    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);
    if (empty($userName)) {
        $error = true;
        $userNameError = "Please enter your User Name.";
    }
    if (empty($pass)) {
        $error = true;
        $passError = "Please enter your password.";
    }
    if (!$error) {
        $password = hash('sha256', $pass);
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT userId, userName, userPass, role FROM users1 WHERE userName='$userName'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        var_dump($count);
        $count == 1 && $row['userPass'] == $password && $row['role'] == 'multirole';
        $multirole = $row['role'];
        $row['userPass'] == ($password);
        switch ($multirole) {
            case "admin":
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userName'];
                $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
                header('Location: admin/home.php');
                break;
            case "user":
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userName'];
                $_SESSION['role'] = 'user';
                header('Location: user/home.php');
                break;
            default:
                echo "No User Found ! Please Contact Admin";
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your script is very bad formatted !

**I think your problem is in this part :**

*$count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password && $row['role']=='multirole';*

$row['role']=='multirole'; // This couldn't be true !

I try to re write your script (by using +- your logic which is not really proper either !) :

```
ob_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if( isset($_POST['btn-login']) )
{
 $username = $_POST['userName'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

 if(empty($userName))
 {
  $error = true;
  $userNameError = "Please enter your User Name.";
 }
 elseif(empty($pass))
 {
  $error = true;
  $userNameError = "Please enter your password.";
 }
 else
 {
  $password = hash('sha256', $pass);

  $res = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE userName = :userName");

  $res -> execute (array (":userName" => $userName));

  $count = $res -> rowCount();

      if($count == 1)
      {
       $rows = $res -> fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            $db_password= $row['userPass'];
            $multirole = $row["role"];
        }

                if($password == $db_password)
                {
                 switch ($multirole)
                 {
                  case "admin":
                  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userName'];
                  $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
                  header('Location: admin/home.php');
                  break;
                  case "user":
                  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userName'];
                  $_SESSION['role'] = 'user';
                  header('Location: user/home.php');
                  break;
                  default:
                  echo "No User Found ! Please Contact Admin";
                 }
                }
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: not work their is somting missing in the coding might be usname and password object not properly set

Comment: @BillyBarret it's possible, the best way to find the problem is to start testing your code part by part ! it means just test if your data posted with if and else and echo a message for each condition ! so you will find where the problem is !